# log4j - logging System.out and System.err concurrently to the console

Tags: java, log4j, out

We have a java webapp which schedules and runs several other tools in variety of languages /java, perl, bash, python etc.../ and  'eats' their out/err streams using StreamGobblers for troubleshooting purposes;

Is it possible to use log4j /in a core java app/ to log both System.err and System.out so they can be captured in the way described above?

Will this not lead to out and err messages interleaving /appearing out of order/?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. log4j can be used to log to both System.err and System.out in to a separate file/stream.

Yes. The messages can be interleaved.

Comment: @aglassman I just tried it,  both out and err are logged to the console /with black and red/ but some messages are out of order. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  Check out this documentation:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html

Comment: Yes, I know I should use or subclass ConsoleAppender but I will need to have 2 - one for out and 1 for err printing to the same stream. I am pretty sure they will interleave at best.

Comment: Log statements shouldn't be interleaved unless you have multiple processes / threads logging to the same log.  If possible, you could sort the logs based on date afterwards.